# USB LG Drive Not seen

Tags: macos

Have Imac with Maverick and Windows 7 running in Parallels 10. Have a LG USB disk drive that is seen by Win 7 and works with no problems. Spins up, displays and works. It is NOT seen by Imac. Every place I look shows no signs of USB drive. It is plugged in same USB port as when it is used in Win 7. How do I get Imac to see the drive?

Comment: Can you see the drive if you eject it from within Windows, shutdown Windows *and* Parallels and then plug in the disk again?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by changing the setting in Parallels under 'Preferences / Devices' to mirror windows-connected devices and then clicking the + button to add all devices that I wanted to access...note, just click the +, and the devices magically appear ;).  Also make sure that the USB drive is formatted as FAT32 or the mac won't see it!